# What can be bitcoin's secret can be at most and at least?

Tags: public-key

We know that: **S(Secret-Scalar) x G(Generater Point-Point(X,Y)) = Public Key**

In bitcoin, what is the range of that secret can be? What can it be at most and at least? Is there a limit to it like 2^256? If yes what is the logic behind that too?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The maximum and minimum private key possible is defined by ECDSA and the curve being used. In ECDSA, the private key is an integer between `1` and `n - 1`, where `n` is the order of the generator point `G`. Bitcoin uses the secp256k1 curve whose generator has an order `n = 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFEBAAEDCE6AF48A03BBFD25E8CD0364141`, which is almost `2^256`.

This means that the minimum value for a private key is `1` and the maximum is `0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFEBAAEDCE6AF48A03BBFD25E8CD0364140`. If you use an integer outside of this range, taking the modulo `n` of that integer will give you a value that is in the valid range (except for multiples of `n` for which the modulo is zero).

Comment: Pedantic nit: if you use an integer that is a multiple of `n`, taking the modulus with `n` will not give you a valid value (but any other integer will work).